# Modify WooCommerce backorder message

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So here goes... 
I have a wordpress site and use woocommerce etc etc. I want to change the backorder message on the product pages to something like “please allow 2 – 4 weeks for delivery of this item” which i’m having issues with.

I also want the same or similar message to show in the shopping cart page where the backorder message usually displays under the item name.

Alternatively, but not my preference, just hide the backorder message from the cart page altogether, but still have it on the product page.

I’m inputting the php code through a plugin rather than using a child theme or mucking about with other things. I usually manage ok, but completely stumped at this. I spent hours on this yesterday and managed to crash my site and everything! lol…

I think it would give a much more professional look to my site.

A link to one of the products on backorder on my site is below so that you can see exactly what i’m looking for.

https://ascentsofscotland.co.uk/product/cormag-celtic-bangle/

Any help is greatly appreciated with this as i'm beginning to get frustrated with something that should in theory be simple... (I think it should actually be a customisable part in woocommerce anyway!)

Thanks in advance to all you genius people out there!

Stu

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you need to filter the [`woocommerce_get_availability_text`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.14/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L722). Add this to your theme's `functions.php` or to a site-specific "snippets" plugin.

```
function so_42345940_backorder_message( $text, $product ){
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {
        $text = __( 'Please allow 2 – 4 weeks for delivery of this item', 'your-textdomain' );
    }
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'so_42345940_backorder_message', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for this... unfortunately it didn't work. I added it by copying and pasting but the backorder message remained exactly the same in all areas of the site. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is your theme hard-coding that message? Do you have any template overrides? Can you temporarily disable them (WooCommerce->System Status>Tools>Template Debug Mode). What about switching your theme entirely. I double-checked that the filter is available in 2.6.14 so this ought to work (in theory).

Comment: I'm using a plugin to enter the code (My Custom Functions) by Arthur Gareginyan. It has worked fine for all the other things I've needed to do by just copying and pasting the code in. Although I built this site myself on the Mystile theme, I still consider my self a bit of a novice, so do I possibly need to do something else? Should I try entering the code somewhere else?

Comment: +1 for using a site-specific snippets plugin. Please try disabling the template overrides like I mentioned, and perhaps even switching to a default theme to rule out conflicts from your theme.

Comment: You are right, this doesn't seem to be doing what I expected. Let me dig a little further.

Comment: Bit of a facepalm with my variable names not matching. Please try the edited code. It's tested and [working](https://wc26-helgatheviking.c9users.io/product/woo-single-2/).

Comment: We're getting there! It now displays the new message in the product page so progress is being made! The shopping cart still shows the standard backorder message though. Any ideas?

Comment: Sadly, that seems to be hard-coded into the [`cart.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.14/templates/cart/cart.php#L90-L93) template. You will need to override that template in order to change it, but be aware that WC2.7 will update that template soon so you'll need to update yours to match.

Comment: sorry for the delay on coming back to you. Thankyou so much for all your help with this! Fantastic! Can you tell me, is there a way to code into my custom coder to hide it from the cart then? or is this the same as trying to change the message?    Thanks again!

Comment: If you are up for it, I would try submitting a pull request to WooCommerce to change that cart template to maybe use `$product->get_availability_text()` there instead of hard-coding. Then my filter will work there too. From the template it looks like the message is wrapped in a `<p class="backorder_notification">` so you could target the `backorder_notification` class with CSS.

Comment: Thanks again! This seems to be getting quite complicated for such a simple thing! I assume to do this with woocommerce I just email them? You know i'm going to nip your brain now and ask how to do this using css??? hehe, sorry, but you seem very knowledgable!      Thanks again

Comment: As I mentioned above, target `.backorder_notification { display: none; }` I guess alternatively, there is a setting that prevents backordering, then you'd probably never see this message at all.

Comment: Thanks soo much Helga!

Comment: Could somebody please explain the 'your-textdomain' part?

Comment: @ejjl It is a "Unique identifier for retrieving translated strings".

Answer (score 3):

Here's an all in one that works in both the product page and the cart (I use the free "Code Snippets" plugin to handle this instead of messing with functions.php files):

```
function alt_message() {
  return "This item may take 3-4 weeks to deliver";
}

function backorder_text($availability) {
$altmessage = alt_message();
foreach($availability as $i) {
$availability = str_replace('Available on backorder', $altmessage, $availability);
}
return $availability;
} 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_availability', 'backorder_text');


function woocommerce_custom_cart_item_name( $_product_title, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
$altmessage = alt_message();
  if ( $cart_item['data']->backorders_require_notification() && $cart_item['data']->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
$_product_title .=  __( ' - '. $altmessage, 'woocommerce' ) ;
}
return $_product_title;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'woocommerce_custom_cart_item_name', 10, 3);
```

Also add the following CSS code in the style.css file of your child theme

```
.backorder_notification{
display: none;
}
.backorder_notification.custom{
display: block;
}
```

PS: If you don’t add CSS code then it will not work.

credit to: http://www.northmore.net/change-backorder-text-woocommerce/